# Using filtering, ordering, and pagination together efficiently with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have been implementing the ability to filter a table based on different fields and at first it seemed fairly straight forward, but now things are getting more complex and I want to make sure I am utilizing Angular's Digest cycle effectively.

Right now, when the user first hits a view and the controller gets instantiated, I call the API and GET an array of data from the server.  I call this data a `dataSet`. This is the raw, unfiltered array of data.

Then on the page there are two different ways to filter, a search bar (`<input>`) and an actual filter menu where the user can toggle different values On/Off and have the table update accordingly in real-time.  At first I thought it would be simple enough to place the filter logic inline inside of `ng-repeat` using a pipe, however this doesn't work with my pagination because the pagination continues to reflect the `dataSet` and not the filtered data.  This led my HTML to look like

```
<tr ng-repeat="mailbox in model.IndividualMailboxes.filtered | orderBy:model.IndividualMailboxes.ordering.predicate:model.IndividualMailboxes.ordering.reverse | paginate:(model.IndividualMailboxes.currentPage - 1) * model.IndividualMailboxes.resultsPerPage | limitTo:model.IndividualMailboxes.resultsPerPage">
```

This then led me to creating a second array that I call `filtered`. I basically filter the `dataSet` array into this new `filtered` array. Then my `ng-repeat` and pagination both use the `filtered` set.    This also forced me to place the actual filter in the controller and use `filterFilter(arr, term)` to filter the `dataSet` in 2 stages

```
function filterIndividualMailboxes() {

            var verifiedList = [], searchList = [];

            verifiedList = filterFilter($scope.model.IndividualMailboxes.dataSet, { Valid : $scope.model.IndividualMailboxes.showVerified });

            searchList = filterFilter(verifiedList, $scope.model.IndividualMailboxes.search);

            $scope.model.IndividualMailboxes.filtered = searchList;

        }
```

The above function simply filters the `dataSet` by our filtering options (there is only 1 in this case) and then takes that set and filters it based on the search term that the user can input.

The problem with this implementation is it doesn't seem to fit into the digest cycle efficiently as I am having to call `filterIndividualMailboxes()` whenever the data is changed in any way.  The easiest way to implement that was to just `$watch()` the entire model like this

```
$scope.$watch('model.IndividualMailboxes', function(){
      filterIndividualMailboxes();
 }, true);
```

But I am afraid that this isn't very efficient and not the most fluid way to deal with filtering in Angular.

Does anyone know of a more "Angular" way of doing this that fits right into the digest cycle?

Comment: How did you implement the pagination?

Comment: I used Angular UI Bootstrapped Pagination